# Can someone tell me why my listView isn't populating with the JSON data

Tags: java, android, json

I have figured out that my main issue right now is my intent code. I have no idea how to build my intent to make the data come back from the website so if anyone could help me with that, it would be awesome! I am trying to get JSON data from the openweather api and my app will load up the web page instead of bringing it into the list view. Right now with the intent I have, a web page opens up with the data I need. Any help would be great!

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,us&APPID=805bd9f830268d5274c60e41613c28a5";
      private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
      private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btnRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //your button id must be button
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); //your listview ide must be listview


        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);




        final JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject jcity = response.getJSONObject("city");

                        String name = jcity.getString("name");
                        JSONArray wlist = response.getJSONArray("list");


                          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = wlist.getJSONObject(i);


                            String dt = jsonObject.getString("dt");
                            JSONArray warray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");

                                JSONObject wobj = warray.getJSONObject(0);
                                String desc = wobj.getString("description");


                                items.add(dt + " " + desc);



                                Log.d("date", dt);  //Log.d prints to the terminal
                                Log.d("desc", desc);//good for debugging


                            }

                            mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                                    (getApplicationContext(),
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

                            //lv.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");

                    }
                }
        );


        btnRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                requestQueue.add(jor);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);

            }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because you missed the setting adapter to the `ListView`. And also make sure your items have data inside it .

```
mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items); 
lv.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: I did have the lv.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter) in there before, but I tried to take it out to see if it would do anything different and it didnt. Even with that code back in there my listView does not populate

Comment: The app will run and when I hit the request data button, it will open the web page to the information I need, but it wont bring the information back to the listView

Comment: Adapter is responsible for show dataset as list item in list view . So if you don't set it list won't populate. On other hand the problem you mentioned in second  comment is completely different . I suggest you to go step by step,  Debug your code and do research on the functionality you want . Cause it is not clear to me .